# Does an unbounded gradient implies a non-vanishing hessian determinant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, hessian-matrix

Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R^{n-1}\to R}$ be a vector function. Suppose that there exists a set $S_1\subset \mathbb R^{n-1}$ on which $G=\nabla\Phi$, the gradient of the function is unbounded.

Does that imply necessarily that there exists a set $S_2$ on which the Hessian determinant $H=\det (\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial x_i\partial x_j})$  or at least one of the eigenvalues is non-vanishing?

Comment: @user1952009 I meant gradient. Thanks.

Comment: if the gradient is unbounded on the neighborhood of $x=a $ there exists $k$ such that $ \frac{\partial \phi}{x_k}$  is unbounded on the neighborhood of $x=a$ so that it reduces to the 1 dimensional case $f(x_k) = \phi(x_k,a)$, and if $f$ is twice differentiable then $f'$ unbounded $\implies f''$ unbounded

Comment: and finally, since $H$ is symmetric, by the spectral theorem its eigenvalues are $\ge 0$, and $tr(H) = \sum \lambda(H)$ is unbounded hence some of its eigenvalues are unbounded

Comment: @user1952009 how the positive definiteness of the Hessian follows from the spectral theorem?

Comment: @user1952009 sorry about the late response but I wonder now also about $f$: if $f''$ is unbounded why does it imply that the Hessian det is unbounded?

Comment: If you neglect your statement, you assume the contrary that all the eigenvalues of the Hessian vanish. Then $H$ is the zero matrix, and thus the gradient is constant (so it is not unbounded). @Differential

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(x,y) = x^2.$ Then $\nabla f(x,y) = (2x,0)$ is unbounded. But the determinant of the Hessian matrix of $f$ is $0$ everywhere.